# Missing 100GB when trying to install Linux

Tags: macos, disk-utility

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also does anyone know if it's safe to delete the disk0s5, disk0s1 and disk0s3?

Edit: oh yeah and here's the error i got when trying to install it again: [image]
and the log: https://www.mediafire.com/file/w7j883pjdend8o9/installer.log/file

[image]
There's also this error when i try to delete it using terminal

Comment: Do not delete `disk0s1` because it contains part of the firmware that is required to boot your mac.

Comment: Do not delete `disk0s5` either because it contains the recoveryOS. I doubt if macOS will even allow you to delete these partitions.

Comment: Ok
What about disk0s3?
and the missing 100gb

Comment: Do you have a backup and are willing to start over? Might be easier if you also have hardware that supports internet recovery. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314 Then it’s low risk if your network is good and stable up to test internet recovery to make sure you have an easy safety net without disk0s5

Comment: Is it possible not to wipe my laptop? like any other method?